# RestSharp on Windows Phone no set-cookie in response

Tags: windows-phone-7, cookies, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a problem with using the RestSharp client on the Windows Phone device. Starting form the beginning, I have the ASP.NET Web Api service hosted online. I have a request user address: POST: http://my-service-url.com/token where I send Email and Password as a body parameters and I get 201 status code and a cookie in the response. When I do it in fiddler everything works fine. I also have the functional test for my API which is using the RestSharp which is also working correctly:

```
[Given(@"I fill email and password with correct data and I click log in button")]
public void GivenIFillEmailAndPasswordWithCorrectDataAndIClickLogInButton()
{
        //Delete user if he exists
        _testUserHelper.DeleteTestUser(TestEmail);

        //Create new activated user
        Assert.IsTrue(_testUserHelper.CreateTestUser(TestEmail, TestPassword));

        //Prepare client
        var client = new RestClient(CarRentalsConstants.HostAddress);
        var restRequest = new RestRequest("api/token", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

        //Add parameters to request
        restRequest.AddBody(new { Email = TestEmail, Password = TestPassword });

        //Perform request
        _response = client.Execute(restRequest);
    }

    [When(@"the log in login process finishes")]
    public void WhenTheLogInLoginProcessFinishes()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, _response.StatusCode, _response.Content);
        Assert.IsNotNull(_response.Cookies.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Name == ".ASPXAUTH"););
    }
```

The one above works properly, and the cookie is in the response object.

Now what I try to do on my windows phone looks like this:

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest("token", Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
restRequest.AddBody(new {Email = email, Password = password});
myWebClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, (restResponse, handle) =>
{
    switch (restResponse.StatusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.Created:
        {
            var cookie = restResponse.Cookies.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Name == ".ASPXAUTH");
            successLogicDelegate(cookie);
        }
        break;
        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
        {
            HandleBadRequest(restResponse.Content, failureLogicDelegate);
        }
        break;
        default:
        msgBox.Show(StringResources.ServerConnectionError);
        failureLogicDelegate(null);
        break;
   }
});
```

And in this case, the response returns the "Created" status code, but the cookie is then set to null. I have no idea what is happening here, but I am fairly certain that server is sending this cookie, so where does it get lost?

Any help will be really appreciated.